# Can a Greek EASA Part 66 License be converted to a German EASA Part 66 License?

Tags: easa-regulations

I want to convert my Greece Part 66 license to a German Part 66 license. What procedure do I have to follow?

Answer (score 1):

You have to send the request to the Greek Authority.
They will contact the German one, and the German Auth. will probably contact you to fill a Form 19.
(details depend of the Auth. procedures)

Comment: This is helpful, Do you have access to any Greek or German reference material that would help back up this answer? If so, [edit] in links (with appropriate quotes in the body of the answer) to make it a great answer.